# Unable to install Magic-link Extension in Keycloak Kubernetes installation

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, keycloak-rest-api

I have installed the Keycloak using the bitnami/keycloak chart and it seems working fine, but I couldn’t find an option to install additional Extensions like keycloak-magic-link. We need to install an add-on.

I could see a git to build the jar file, but not sure how can we use it inside the Kubernetes pods, can you please add the instruction to install Extensions also. I can’t find an example for the same, no documentation is available on the public internet to solve this issue.

Extensions link from the official Keycloak site: https://github.com/p2-inc/keycloak-magic-link

Where can I get the file show we build it using `mvm clean install` command as instructed in the doc? if so we have the jar file on how to build it inside the Keycloak container.

I couldn’t see a standalone/deployment directory inside the Keycloak directory. Please help me if any one familiar with the setup.

Thanks